# Identification: creepy dangling spiderthing

Tags: species-identification

Can anyone identify this creepy mess dangling from the cieling of my garage on a few strands of spidersilk? The thing is 5cm.

[image: nope nope nope]

Should I burn down my garage and move to another country (Currently Belgium)?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it now. Have a look at this:
https://fireflyafrica.blogspot.com/2009/03/rain-spider-nest.html
it features a nest, large ("tennis ball" sized), hanging from threads, and they claim it is a "rain spider" nest, but rain spiders do not seem to span Belgium.

I am not familiar with what a 'Rain spider' is, so looking it up,'rain spider' is a genus of the Huntsman spider family, and there are huntsman spiders in Belgium. But huntsman spiders are known to carry their own (small pouch) egg sacs.

Looking up "rain spider nest" finds many photos similar to yours. But I cannot find any that live in Belgium or Europe.

This is probably on the right path, and you can try searching for various cousins or other relatives of the 'rain spider' that might be in Belgium.

Comment: Well, it's more pingpong ball sized, so I think it'll be the egg sack of a rather ambitious Tegenaria

Comment: Stored prey? for a couple of years?